# Adapt vim regexes to expand context.vim to show context for sql results

Tags: regex, vim

Hi I am trying to expand the plugin [context.vim](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim) to include table headers from sql query results (received from the [vim-dadbod](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod) and [vim-dadbod-ui](https://github.com/kristijanhusak/vim-dadbod-ui) plugins) in the context.

I think I am nearly there.
[image]

I set the following
`let g:context_extend_regex = '^\s*\([]{})]\|end\|else\|\(case\|default\|done\|elif\|fi\|-\{5,}\|\(-\+\s\+\)\+-\+$\)\>\)'` and `let g:context_join_regex = '^\W*$\|\(\w\+\s\+\)\+\n^--'`
But I think my regex for `context_join_regex` is not right, as the function responsible for checking the regex in context.vim seems to check lines, hence, the new line followed by dashes will not be matched.

I wonder how I can adjust that regex to work as intended.

Demotable to test the regexes on:

```
ColOne               ColTwo     ColThree             ColFour                 
-------------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------------------
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                iiii       jjjj        kkkkkkkkkkkkk          mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
let g:context_extend_regex = '^-\+'
let g:context_join_regex = '^[^-]\+'
let g:context_skip_regex = '^-\+'
```

[image: screenshot]

If you want to keep the dashed line under header, don't define `g:context_skip_regex`.